# What plant/tree is this?

Tags: identification, trees

I found it like this in front of my door on the pavement. Most likely either dropped there by a bird.Is it a tree?
Location: South of Ireland 
[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not a tree but I've forgotten its name - if its popped up on its own and wasn't there last year, its technically a weed, but either way, it  doesn't get very big... if I remember what  its  called, I'll come back to this thread...

Comment: Thanks @Bamboo .  It did not sprout. It just sat there on the concrete. Not sure how it got there.Birds maybe.

Comment: Are the leaves attached opposite or alternate on the stem?

Comment: Could it be purple loosestrife (lythrum salicaria ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is a weed that also grows on walls here. I have since discarded it thanks for all the comments.